# Encoding Problem with Zend Navigation using Zend Translate Spanish in XMLTPX File Special Characters

Tags: php, zend-framework, special-characters, zend-navigation, zend-translate

I have been attempting to use Zend Translate to display translated menu items to the user.

It works fine until I introduce special characters into the translation files.

I instantiate the Zend_Translate object in my bootstrap and pass it in as a translator into Zend_Navigation:

```
$translate = new Zend_Translate(
    array('adapter' => 'tmx',
          'content' => APPLICATION_PATH .'/languages/translation.tmx',
          'locale' => 'es'
          )
);

$navigation->setUseTranslator($translate);
```

I have used several different adapters (array,tmx) in order to see if that made a difference. I ended up with a TMX file that is encoded using ISO-8859-1 (otherwise that throws an XML parse error when introducing the menu item "Administrar Applicación".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE tmx SYSTEM "tmx14.dtd">
<tmx version="1.4">
    <header creationtoolversion="1.0.0" datatype="tbx" segtype="sentence"
        adminlang="en" srclang="en" o-tmf="unknown"
        creationtool="XYZTool" >
    </header>
    <body>
        <tu tuid='link_signout'>
            <tuv xml:lang="en"><seg>Sign Out</seg></tuv>
            <tuv xml:lang="es"><seg>Salir</seg></tuv>
        </tu>
        <tu tuid='link_signin'>
            <tuv xml:lang="en"><seg>Login</seg></tuv>
            <tuv xml:lang="es"><seg>Acceder</seg></tuv>
        </tu>
        <tu tuid='Manage Application'>
            <tuv xml:lang="en"><seg>Manage Application</seg></tuv>
            <tuv xml:lang="es"><seg>Administrar Applicación</seg></tuv>
        </tu>
    </body>
</tmx>
```

Once I display the menu in the layout:

```
echo $this->navigation()->menu();
```

It will display all menu items just fine, EXCEPT the one using special characters. It will simply be blank.

NOW - If I use PHP's UTF8-encode inside of the zend framework class 'Menu' which I DO NOT want to do:

Line 215 in Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu:

```
if ($this->getUseTranslator() && $t = $this->getTranslator()) {
    if (is_string($label) && !empty($label)) {
        $label = utf8_encode($t->translate($label));
    }
    if (is_string($title) && !empty($title)) {
        $title = utf8_encode($t->translate($title));
    }
}
```

Then it works. The menu item display correctly and all is joyful.

The thing is, I do not want to modify the library.

Is there some kind of an encoding setting in either zend translate or zend navigation that I am not finding?

Please Help!

Zend Library Version: 1.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a related problem: zend form didn't display latin characters like ñ. Try adding the following to your _initView function in bootstrap.php:

```
$view->setEncoding('iso-8859-1');
```